# Common Lisp `case` on `read` with custom package

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp, user-input, sbcl

Following code from Paul G's *OnLisp* works fine if I run it in REPL without custom package. When I define a package and use it with `(in-package :mypackage)` it does not work -- it always takes the `t` case in the `case` statement:

```
(defun run-node (name)
 (let ((n (gethash name *nodes*)))
  (cond ((node-yes n)
         (format t "~A~%>> " (node-contents n))
         (case (read)
           (yes (run-node (node-yes n))) ; never hits this in package
           (t (run-node (node-no n))))) 
        (t (node-contents n)))))
```

Comment: It always helps to properly format your code, indent your code and provide a reproducible test case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all be aware that what you are doing is insanely dangerous: unconstrained calls to `read` can cause the program to execute *any code whatsoever*.  If you *must* call `read` for user input, call it in a safe way:

```
(with-standard-io-syntax
  (let ((*read-eval* nil)
        (*package* ...))
    (read)))
```

Secondly, indent your code so people can read it:

```
(defun run-node (name)
  (let ((n (gethash name *nodes*)))
    (cond ((node-yes n)
           (format t "~A~%>> " (node-contents n))
           (case (read)
             (yes (run-node (node-yes n))) ;never hits this in package
             (t (run-node (node-no n))))) 
          (t (node-contents n)))))
```

And now we can annotate your code (adding in some minimal `read`-defanging while we're at it) to show you what the bug is:

```
(defun run-node (name)
  (with-standard-io-syntax
    (let ((n (gethash name *nodes*))
          (*read-eval* nil))
      (cond ((node-yes n)
             (format t "~A~%>> " (node-contents n))
             (let ((got (read)))
               (format *debug-io*
                       "~&*package* ~16T~A~%got package~16T~A~%our package~16T~A~%"
                       (package-name *package*)
                       (typecase got
                         (symbol (package-name (symbol-package got)))
                         (t "(not a symbol"))
                       (package-name (symbol-package 'yes)))
               (case got
                 (yes (run-node (node-yes n))) ;never hits this in package
                 (t (run-node (node-no n))))))
            (t (node-contents n))))))
```

What you're going to find is that the package of the symbol you've read is not the same as the package of the symbol you are comparing it against, so the symbols are different.